# DownloadFileAsync stuck in loop C#

Tags: c#

I want to download multiple image in a website. The link for query has a format:

```
abc.com/GetImage.aspx?MSSV=0101012018
```

When I use `DownloadFileAsync()` method in **WebClient** class in C#, it's still work if I only get 1 image. But when I try to get multiple image, I put it in loop. If it reach out loop, then return MessageBox contain string: "Download complete" or "Download failed".

But when I run it, when reach out of loop, it stuck in `wc_DownloadProgressChanged()` method and never go to `wc_DownloadFileComplete()` to print out message.

```
private void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
private void wc_DownloadFileComplete(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Download sucessfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
    ((WebClient)sender).Dispose();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int mssv = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    int amount = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();                
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);                    
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("abc.com/GetImage.aspx?MSSV="+mssv), mssv.ToString()+".jpg");
        mssv++;
        if (i == amount)
        {
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileComplete);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you only attach the `DownloadFileCompleted` event handler when `i == amount`? That is your problem, only the last call of the loop will print the completed output.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: change `if (i == amount)` to `if (i == amount - 1)`. Another problem - you're not waiting `wc.DownloadFileAsync()` call. There are couple of ways to do that. One of it:  mark your method as `async void` (need to be careful with exceptions) and use `await wc.DownloadFileAsync()`.

Comment: @DmitryPavliv This is not that kind of async so no awaits. This is event driven async.

Answer (score 1):

This block of code will NEVER be executed because your for-loop condition checks `i < amount`.  So `i` will never equal `amount` inside the loop. It will always be less-than.

```
if (i == amount)
{
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileComplete);
}
```

Multiple ways you could correct this...

1. Change the for-loop to

   ```
   for(int i = 1; i <= amount; i++)
   ```
2. Change the `if` statement to

   ```
   if (i == amount-1 )
   ```
3. Move the `DownloadFileCompleted` event handler outside of the loop and reuse the `WebClient` (untested).

   ```
   WebClient wc = null;
   for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
   {
       progressBar1.Value = 0;
       wc = new WebClient();
       wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);                        
       wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("abc.com/GetImage.aspx?MSSV="+mssv), mssv.ToString()+".jpg");
       mssv++;
   }
   if( wc != null )
       wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileComplete);
   ```
4. My personal recommendation... As it stands now, your progress bar is going to be all over the place as different downloads report progress. (also untested, and I probably made several typos).

   ```
   private void wc_DownloadFileComplete(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       progressBar1.PerformStep();
       if( e.Error != null )
       {
           string msg = String.Format("Error downloading MSSV {0}\r\n\r\n{1}",progressBar1.Value,e.Error.Message);
           MessageBox.Show(msg);
       }
       if( progressBar1.Maximum == progressBar1.Value )
       {
           MessageBox.Show("All downloads completed.");
           WebClient wc = sender as WebClient;
           if( wc != null )
               wc.Dispose();
       }
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int mssv = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
       int amount = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
       progressBar1.Value = 0;
       progressBar1.Maximum = amount;
       WebClient wc = new WebClient();
       wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileComplete);
       for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++, mssv++)
       {
           Uri url = new Uri(String.Format("abc.com/GetImage.aspx?MSSV={0}",mssv));
           string path = String.Format("{0}.jpg",mssv);
           wc.DownloadFileAsync(url,path);
       }
   }
   ```

Additionally, I question your logic of adding the event handler after the call to `DownloadFileAsync`. It'll probably never ever happen, but theoretically, the call to `DownloadFileAsync` could complete before the event handler is added. It would really be best to add the event handler before the call to `DownloadFileAsync`.